# Convert a sequence of strings to integers (Clojure)

Tags: string, clojure, type-conversion

I currently am having an issue where I have to read a text file from the command line containing at least one integer. I'm reading the file, doing a regular-expression match to ignore whitespace.

```
(re-seq #"[0-9]+" (slurp (first *command-line-args*)))
```

After this I have to write a whole function just to convert this sequence of strings into a sequence of integers. Apparently I cannot map `Integer.` to the sequence (unless I am using map incorrectly).

Is there some elegant way of handling this, something similar to map? Or do I have to go through recursively popping off first and casting it to `Integer.` to get this to work?

I am currently learning Clojure, and as I learn bits I am going back and doing little programmer quizzes I used to pick up other languages.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're looking for `Integer/parseInt`.

```
user=> (map #(Integer/parseInt %) ["1" "2" "3" "4"])
(1 2 3 4)
```

You have to wrap `Integer/parseInt` in an anonymous function because Java methods aren't functions.

`read-string` would also work in this case:

```
user=> (map read-string ["1" "2" "3" "4"])
(1 2 3 4)
```

`read-string` reads *any* object from a string, not just integers. So, if you did `(read-string "1.0")` you'd get back a double. When reading from outside sources, it's usually better to limit what can be read to precisely what you need, which is an integer in this case. Therefore, I recommend using my first example.

Comment: +1 Had no idea about read-string, but knew there must be something like it

Comment: This works very well, but only when clojure is running on the JVM. ClojureCLR isn't

Comment: If people answered Clojure questions with answers that worked on every implementation of Clojure, you'd have some pretty terrible code and some pretty long, tired answers. It's perfectly acceptable to ask questions specifically about the implementation of Clojure you're using.

Comment: I personally don't see any reason to favor `Integer/parseInt` in this case. The `re-seq` already makes sure there are only numbers in these strings anyway. And `read-string` would automatically coerce numbers that are too large to `BigInt`. In any case, if you insist on using the java number classes, it should really have been Long you're using (because that's what Clojure itself uses internally).

Comment: @Cubic Note that this answer was written in January of 2011, before Clojure defaulted to Longs. Furthermore, there is nothing wrong with using read-string, but it is a huge security hole. See Clojure's eval-reader. You can fix that by binding `*read-eval*` to false. If you mistakenly don't do this in a single piece of user-facing code, you've opened yourself up to very easy injection attacks. I don't usually recommend read-string for these sorts of things.

Comment: FWIW, I read on another SO question that `Integer/parseInt` is significantly (10x, if I remember correctly?) faster than `read-string`, and there was benchmarking proof. If you're confident that your input will be integers, `Integer/parseInt` is the better option for performance.