# Parsing lines of a file with mixed types in Clojure

Tags: parsing, clojure

Say I have a file with lines that look like this `apple,pie,100,1000`. From each line I would like to have a vector like this `["apple" "pie" 100 1000]`, where the first two are strings and the second to are integers or Longs or whatever.

A solution could be

```
(defn foo [line]
  (let [[a b c d] (split line #",")]
    [a b (Integer/parseInt c) (Integer/parseInt d)]))
```

which does what I want, but I'm not sure if there may be a better (or more idiomatic) way to do this or not.

From this question [What's the easiest way to parse numbers in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640169/whats-the-easiest-way-to-parse-numbers-in-clojure) , I found out about clojure.edn, so I could use `read-line` like this

```
(map read-string (clojure.string/split "apple,pie,12,134" #","))
;=> (:apple :pie 12 134)
```

but that gives me symbols instead of strings.

This question [Convert a sequence of strings to integers (Clojure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714923/convert-a-sequence-of-strings-to-integers-clojure) is also similar, except that the lines contain only numbers and not numbers and strings.

Note: clojure-csv (https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv) and clojure.data.csv (https://github.com/clojure/data.csv) don't appear to have a function that automatically does this.

Comment: "Better" depends on what you want to do with the data. You could convert symbols to strings with `name`, or you could use a csv library, have a schema, etc. Perhaps your question needs more context.

Comment: When you said schema, were you talking about https://github.com/Prismatic/schema?

Comment: By better, I mean more idiomatic. Maybe there is something in one of the clojure namespaces or a 3rd party library, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv) to parse your data and Prismatic's [schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) to coerce field values to the desired types:

```
;; [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]
;; [prismatic/schema "0.2.2"]

(require '[schema.core :as s]
         '[schema.coerce :as coerce]
         '[clojure.data.csv :as csv])

(def field-schemas [s/Str s/Str s/Int s/Int])
(def field-coercers
  (mapv coerce/coercer
    field-schemas
    (repeat coerce/string-coercion-matcher)))

(defn coerce-fields [fields]
  (mapv #(%1 %2) field-coercers fields))
```

And finally:

```
(map coerce-fields (csv/read-csv "apple,pie,12,134"))
;= (["apple" "pie" 12 134])
```

Comment: Can you desbribe a bit what it does at each step?

Comment: @leontalbot Sure. Prismatic's schema has the concepts of "schemas" which a value can match or not and "coercers" which know how to transform certain kinds of values which do not match a schema into values that do, for example by parsing a string representation of a number or creating a keyword from a string. AFAICT schemas for heterogeneous sequences / vectors are not supported out of the box, so I opted for a vector-of-schemas approach -- that's `field-schemas`. (Introducing a proper schema type for heterogeneous sequences would be a tad more involved, though not particularly difficult --

Comment: I'm just not sure that it would be a huge win for this simple use case.) `field-coercers` is an accompanying vector of coercers; `string-coercion-matcher` is a schema built-in that knows how to perform the most common coercions. `coerce-fields` takes a seqable of values and uses field-coercers to coerce the values to types specified in `field-schemas`.

Comment: It accomplishes this by mapping `#(%1 %2)` -- a function that applies its first argument (presumably itself a function) to its second argument -- across `field-coercers` and `fields`; thus a field will be coerced using the coercer in the matching position in `field-coercers`. Finally, `read-csv` parses CSV into a sequence of vectors representing the individual records; each such vector is in the shape expected by `coerce-fields`. What this doesn't do is validate the length of those vectors; this would be easy enough to add though.

Comment: You're probably right in that it isn't worth it for this simple case, but something like this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: I think a proper schema type would perhaps not be worth the trouble to implement, but the approach with a vector of schemas implemented in the answer does seem like a good fit for the task at hand to me. Anyway, happy to hear this may be useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a library out there that makes this very easy. Can't remember the name of it but it worked like so

```
(let [structure [str str int int]]
 (map #(% %2) 
      structure
      (map read-string (clojure.string/split "apple,pie,12,134" #",")))
;=> ("apple" "pie" 12 134)
```

Comment: Something like this would be great. I will have to do some looking and see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but

```
(map numberise (clojure.string/split "apple,pie,12,134" #","))
; ("apple" "pie" 12 134)
```

where

```
(defn numberise [s]
  (try (Integer/parseInt s)
       (catch NumberFormatException nfe s)))
```

Comment: @Sandy Rarely used, from what I've seen, but I'm just a tinkerer. The prevailing idiom seems to be to return `nil` from a function that can't produce a substantive result. So `try` - `catch` is not in play. For example, `({1 :a} 0)` returns `nil` (a couple of counter-examples are `([] 3)` and `(int "123")`, which both throw exceptions). I suppose Java inter-op, as above, is the main area where exceptions occur and therefore `try` - `catch` is employed. *What are the legitimate uses for `try` - `catch` in Clojure* sounds like a reasonable question to me.